# Ext JS 3 - Disable sort on click of a grid column header

Tags: javascript, extjs

When sort is enabled in a column, clicking the header automatically sorts on that column. I want to disallow sorting based on a click of the column's header but retain sorting through the header's menu. In other words, the only way to sort the column is by entering the header menu. Any thoughts?

Comment: Interesting - why do you need this?

Comment: First I wanted the remove the ability to select columns on and off. Then my need changed to requiring custom menu items in the header. See below for how I coded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var contextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
items: [{
    id: 'sort-high-to-low',
    cls: 'xg-hmenu-sort-asc',
    text: 'Sort Ascending within Group'
},{
    id: 'sort-low-to-high',
    cls: 'xg-hmenu-sort-desc',
    text: 'Sort Descending within Group'
},'-',{
    id: 'sort-high-to-low-all',
    cls: 'xg-hmenu-sort-asc',
    text: 'Sort All Ascending'
},{
    id: 'sort-low-to-high-all',
    cls: 'xg-hmenu-sort-desc',
    text: 'Sort All Descending'
},'-',  {
    id: 'heatmap',
    cls: 'xg-hmenu-heatmap',
    text: 'Open in Heatmap'
}],
listeners: {
    scope: this,
    itemclick: function(item) {
        switch (item.id) {
        case 'sort-high-to-low':
            Ext.getCmp('backtestGrid').getStore().sort(contextMenu.columnId,'ASC');
            this.hide();
            break;
        case 'sort-low-to-high':
            Ext.getCmp('backtestGrid').getStore().sort(contextMenu.columnId,'DESC');
            this.hide();
            break;
        case 'sort-high-to-low-all':
            Ext.getCmp('backtestGrid').getStore().clearGrouping();
            Ext.getCmp('backtestGrid').getStore().sort(contextMenu.columnId,'ASC');
            this.hide();
            break;
        case 'sort-low-to-high-all':
            Ext.getCmp('backtestGrid').getStore().clearGrouping();
            Ext.getCmp('backtestGrid').getStore().sort(contextMenu.columnId,'DESC');
            this.hide();
            break;
        case 'heatmap':
            heatmapCallback(contextMenu.headerName, contextMenu.columnId);
            this.hide();
            break;
        }
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
{
  xtype: 'gridcolumn',
  menuDisabled: true,
  width: '75%'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building my own context menu based on the following post.

[How i can create context menu for extjs grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280101/how-i-can-create-context-menu-for-extjs-grid)

Answer (score 0):

**In Ext 6:**

Override `Ext.grid.column.Column` to condition the `sortOnClick` attribute on the method `onTitleElClick`

I and used a new configuration `enableSortOnClick` to control this.

Setting `enableSortOnClick = false` disables sort on header click but maintains sort functionality on header dropdown menu.

```
Ext.define('App.overrides.ColumnOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',

    config: {
        /** Control sortOnClick at TitleElClick event*/
        enableSortOnClick: false,
    },

    /**@Overrides*/
    onTitleElClick: function(e, t, sortOnClick) {
        return this.callParent([e, t, this.enableSortOnClick && sortOnClick]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You answer needs more explaination about how the code works to be a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?12608-CLOSED-How-to-disable-sorting-by-click-the-header-of-column-in-GridPanel